# me.controls.find won't find toolbar controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a VB.net form with

1. a simple Windows.Forms.TextBox, let's name it input1
2. a toolbar with a Windows.Forms.ToolStripTextBox, let's name it input2

   Me.Controls.Find("input1", True)

works as expected returns an Array with 1 form element.

```
Me.Controls.Find("input2", True)
```

returns an Array with no content.

Well, how Me.controls.find works, is explained [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4eaa665-1a70-4a3e-b865-9b25055b0a3e/mecontrolsfind) and [here](http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/finding-controls-on-forms/), but why it doesn't work in this case? input2 is definitely a child element of Me. -- same as input1.

Comment: Things such as Menus and ToolStrips are `Components` - if there is something in the form tray at the bottom - it is a `Component` and they do not go into the `Controls` collection

Comment: ah, I forgot to mention that I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with a simple Windows Form, no WPF, MDI or other type.

Comment: @plutonix: Ah okay, didn't knew that. Any idea how to search them for a child control (I assume that a ToolStripTextBox is also a control)?

Comment: These ToolStripItem classes do not derive from the Control class so cannot be found through the Controls collection.  You have to start at the ToolStrip object, you can Find() that one, and iterate through the Items collection.

Comment: your `ToolStrip` component has an Items property which is a collection of the things it contains

Comment: great, works with that. Thanks very much!